# R How to install package 'graph'?

Tags: r, graph, package, installation

The package `graph` isn´t available on CRAN anymore. I found that it has moved to Bioconductor, see

[Bioconductor - graph](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/graph.html)

But actually, if I try to run the commands they advise to run

```
install.packages("BiocInstaller")
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("graph")
```

I get the error that even the BiocInstaller is not available for the latest R version 3.4.2

How can I install this package?

Comment: For some special package you indeed may need to use an earlier R version, if you do not have time to wait that the package maintainer updates the package for the newer R version.

Comment: Is it possible to install it manually if I download the .tar.gz file from CRAN Archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works:

First, download the zip file from http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/graph.html

Second, install the package locally:

```
install.packages("yourpath/graph_1.56.0.zip",repos=NULL)
```

Then, `library(graph)` will load the package. You'll get a warning message the package was created unter a different version of R, but it will likely work this way.

Answer (score 3):

See the instructions at http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/graph.html:

> Installation
>
> To install this package, start R (version "3.5") and enter:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("graph", version = "3.8")
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use this command: `install.packages("BiocInstaller")`

This page crosswalks Biconductor version to R version https://www.bioconductor.org/about/release-announcements/

```
> Release   R
> 3.7, 3.8  3.5
> 3.5, 3.6  3.4
> 3.3, 3.4  3.3
```

For R 3.4.2 you need Bioconductor 3.6 https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/3.6/bioc/html/graph.html

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("graph")
```